# Accidentally deleted windows by factory resetting on dual boot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

It started when I dual booted my computer. Later I thought I'd clear some space by factory resetting Windows. So from the settings in windows I tried to factory reset it. About halfway through, something happened and now restarting the computer still shows the grub loader, and ubuntu still works, but when I choose windows, it loads for a while and restarts the computer. Is there any way I could restore Windows?

Additional info:

Dell latitude E6220

Originally came as windows 7 or xp

Upgraded to windows 10 before dual boot

Dual booted with ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory reset probably failed when it encountered the partition and format it didn't expect or know how to deal with. You should be able to manually install Windows 10 if you have a disk for it, but the automated Factory Restore process will generally NOT work if you've partitioned and set up dual-boot.

Answer (score 0):

**>>So from the settings in windows I tried to factory reset it.**

It seems that you are trying to reset Windows 10 from Settings > Update & security > Reset this PC > Get started, as mentioned in this link.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options

I agree with music2myear, it may not work if you've partitioned and set up dual-boot. But, you should be able to perform a clean installation to get Windows 10 back. Considering you are trying to reset Windows 10, which acts like reinstalling Windows, I think it should be acceptable.